# Appears to be a margin right on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make a new website and I have been having issues with Safari, It appears there is so margin-right, despite "overflow-x:hidden" being present, I have isolated the issue to "body", and it has a margin-right but I do not know how to stop it.
[image: The orange to the right of body indicates a margin]
The orange indicates margin.

Here is the code:

```js
//Game List
console.log(document.getElementById('close3').style.display);
function showGameList(){
 document.getElementById("gameList").style.display= "block";
 document.getElementById("close1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("close2").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("close3").style.display = "none";
}
function closeGameList(){
  document.getElementById("gameList").style.display= "none";
  document.getElementById("close1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("close2").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("close3").style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
/*fonts*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');
/*general*/
html{
 max-width: 100vw;
 min-width: 100vw;
 width: 100vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height: auto;
}
body{
 width: 99vw;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 height: auto;
 background-color: black;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 color: white;
 margin-right: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0px;
}
/*Navbar*/
#nav{
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
top: 0%;
padding: none;
}
#navLink{
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 22%;
padding: 1%;
transition: 0.5s;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
#navLink:hover{
 background-color: gold;
 color: black;
}
#navLinkActive{
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 22.5%;
padding: 1%;
transition: 0.5s;
text-align: center;
color: black;
background-color: gold;
}
/*Home page*/
#page{
 max-width: 98.5vw;
 height: auto;
 width: 98.5vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 text-align: center;
}
.joinButton{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border: 5px solid gold;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}
.joinButton:hover{
 background-color: rgba(255,215,0,0.5);
 zoom: 1.25;
}
#homePageBody{
 height: 40vh;
 padding-top: 15vh;
 padding-bottom: 15vh;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px; 
}
#homePageBodySpecial{
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 15vh;
 padding-bottom: 15vh;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px; 
}
#homePageBody p{
font-size: 20px;
}
.homePageBody1{
padding-top: 15vh;
margin-top: 5vh;
 background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) ),    url('assets/images/backgrounds/background1.png');
}
.homePageBody2{
margin-top: 1vh;
height: auto;
min-height: 40vh;
 background-repeat: none;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) ),    url('assets/images/backgrounds/background2.png');
}
/* Game List */
#gameList{
 display: none;
 border: 5px solid gold;
 border-radius: 5%;
 width: 40vw;
 padding:2.5vw;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 transition: 1s;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#gameListItem{
 width: 30%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: auto;
}
#gameListItemImg{
 width: 30%;
}
#closeButtonSmall{
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border:none;
 text-align: center;
 top: 2.5%;
 right: 2.5%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: white;
}
#gameListItemFullWidth{
 width: 100%;
}
#counter1{
}
/*Mobile*/
@media screen and (max-width: 660px){
 #navLink{
  width: 100%;
 }
 #navLinkActive{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>AUG</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Navbar -->
 <div id="nav">
  <a href="" id="navLinkActive"><div id="navItemActive">Home</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">About</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">Join</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">User Center</div></a>
 </div>
 <!-- Main Body -->
 <div id="page">
 <div id="homePageBody" class="homePageBody1">
  <h1>Aussie Games</h1><br>
  <p>Welcome to Aussie Games! We are a developing gaming community that features both indie and mainstream games.<br>
With an enthusiastic, friendly and supportive member base combined with world class Community Support Officers we can help you find the<br> community for you and support you along the way.</p>
  <button class="joinButton">Join us</button><br>
 </div>
 <div id="homePageBodySpecial" class="homePageBody2">
  <h2 id="close1">What we offer</h2><br>
  <p id="close2">We offer great, inclusive communities, and competent staff for many of the games you know.</p>
  <button id="close3" class="joinButton" onclick="showGameList()">What do we offer</button>
  <div id="gameList" onclick="closeGameList()">
   <div id="gameListItemFullWidth"><p>Click window to close</p></div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/FL.png">
   <p>Flashing Lights</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/GM.png">
   <p>Garry's Mod</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/IF.png">
   <p>Infinite Flight</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/KSP.png">
   <p>Kerbal Space Program</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/MC.png">
   <p>Minecraft</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/P2.png">
   <p>Payday 2</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/RB.png">
   <p>Roblox</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/SM.png">
   <p>Surving Mars</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/TF.png">
   <p>Team Fortress</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am also having issues with on small screens button not being taken into padding with the #homePageBody.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be fixed by removing max width on html and min width on html

Answer (score 0):

There is a **width:99vw;** set in the **body{}** element.You need to remove this and it will be good.

-The **HTML{}** element has a **width:100vw;** and body{} has width:99vw; set.So it results in a margin of 1vw.

```js
//Game List
console.log(document.getElementById('close3').style.display);
function showGameList(){
 document.getElementById("gameList").style.display= "block";
 document.getElementById("close1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("close2").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("close3").style.display = "none";
}
function closeGameList(){
  document.getElementById("gameList").style.display= "none";
  document.getElementById("close1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("close2").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("close3").style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
/*fonts*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap');
/*general*/
html{
 max-width: 100vw;
 min-width: 100vw;
 width: 100vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height: auto;
}
body{
 
 max-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100vh;
 height: auto;
 background-color: black;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 color: white;
 margin-right: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0px;
}
/*Navbar*/
#nav{
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
top: 0%;
padding: none;
}
#navLink{
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 22%;
padding: 1%;
transition: 0.5s;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
#navLink:hover{
 background-color: gold;
 color: black;
}
#navLinkActive{
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 22.5%;
padding: 1%;
transition: 0.5s;
text-align: center;
color: black;
background-color: gold;
}
/*Home page*/
#page{
 max-width: 98.5vw;
 height: auto;
 width: 98.5vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 text-align: center;
}
.joinButton{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border: 5px solid gold;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}
.joinButton:hover{
 background-color: rgba(255,215,0,0.5);
 zoom: 1.25;
}
#homePageBody{
 height: 40vh;
 padding-top: 15vh;
 padding-bottom: 15vh;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px; 
}
#homePageBodySpecial{
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 15vh;
 padding-bottom: 15vh;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px; 
}
#homePageBody p{
font-size: 20px;
}
.homePageBody1{
padding-top: 15vh;
margin-top: 5vh;
 background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) ),    url('assets/images/backgrounds/background1.png');
}
.homePageBody2{
margin-top: 1vh;
height: auto;
min-height: 40vh;
 background-repeat: none;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) ),    url('assets/images/backgrounds/background2.png');
}
/* Game List */
#gameList{
 display: none;
 border: 5px solid gold;
 border-radius: 5%;
 width: 40vw;
 padding:2.5vw;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 transition: 1s;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#gameListItem{
 width: 30%;
 display: inline-block;
 height: auto;
}
#gameListItemImg{
 width: 30%;
}
#closeButtonSmall{
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border:none;
 text-align: center;
 top: 2.5%;
 right: 2.5%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: white;
}
#gameListItemFullWidth{
 width: 100%;
}
#counter1{
}
/*Mobile*/
@media screen and (max-width: 660px){
 #navLink{
  width: 100%;
 }
 #navLinkActive{
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>AUG</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Navbar -->
 <div id="nav">
  <a href="" id="navLinkActive"><div id="navItemActive">Home</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">About</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">Join</div></a>
  <a href="" id="navLink"><div id="navItem">User Center</div></a>
 </div>
 <!-- Main Body -->
 <div id="page">
 <div id="homePageBody" class="homePageBody1">
  <h1>Aussie Games</h1><br>
  <p>Welcome to Aussie Games! We are a developing gaming community that features both indie and mainstream games.<br>
With an enthusiastic, friendly and supportive member base combined with world class Community Support Officers we can help you find the<br> community for you and support you along the way.</p>
  <button class="joinButton">Join us</button><br>
 </div>
 <div id="homePageBodySpecial" class="homePageBody2">
  <h2 id="close1">What we offer</h2><br>
  <p id="close2">We offer great, inclusive communities, and competent staff for many of the games you know.</p>
  <button id="close3" class="joinButton" onclick="showGameList()">What do we offer</button>
  <div id="gameList" onclick="closeGameList()">
   <div id="gameListItemFullWidth"><p>Click window to close</p></div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/FL.png">
   <p>Flashing Lights</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/GM.png">
   <p>Garry's Mod</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/IF.png">
   <p>Infinite Flight</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/KSP.png">
   <p>Kerbal Space Program</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/MC.png">
   <p>Minecraft</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/P2.png">
   <p>Payday 2</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/RB.png">
   <p>Roblox</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/SM.png">
   <p>Surving Mars</p>
   </div>
   <div id="gameListItem">
   <img id="gameListItemImg" src="assets/images/gameIcons/TF.png">
   <p>Team Fortress</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```